# Can't open .pdf file after saving .tex file

Tags: errors, conversion

I simply can't open a `.tex` file I wrote and saved as a `.pdf` file.

Here is what I wrote:

```
\documentclass[a4paper,12pt]{article}

\usepackage[a4paper,left=2.54cm,right=2.54cm,top=2.54cm,bottom=2.54cm]{geometry}

\usepackage[croatian]{babel}
\usepackage[utf8]{inputenc}
\usepackage{times}

\usepackage{amsmath}
\usepackage{amssymb}

\usepackage{setspace}
\onehalfspacing

\usepackage{titlesec}
\titleformat{\section}{\fontsize{16pt}{20pt}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesection.}{0.4cm}{}
\titleformat{\subsection}{\fontsize{14pt}{18pt}\selectfont\bfseries}{\thesubsection.}{0.4cm}{}
\setlength{\parskip}{10pt}

\titlespacing*{\section}{0pt}{0.5cm}{0pt}
\titlespacing*{\subsection}{0pt}{0.5cm}{0pt}

\usepackage{enumitem}
\setlist{topsep=3pt,itemsep=3pt}

\usepackage{graphicx}

\usepackage[numbers]{natbib}
\setlength{\bibsep}{2pt}


\begin{document}


\thispagestyle{empty}
\begin{center}
Sveučilište u Zagrebu\\
Fakultet organizacije i informatike
\end{center}
\vfill
\begin{center}
\Large Esej br. $n$: Naziv eseja
\end{center}
\vfill
U Varaždinu, 20.03.2014.\hfill Prezime Ime, grupa G12
\newpage
\setcounter{page}{1}

\section{Numerička integracija}
\par
Osnovna ideja numeričke integracije je približno izračunavanje $I$ ($f$) korištenjem vrijednosti funkcije $f$ na nekom konačnom skupu točaka. Recimo odmah da postoje i integracijske formule koje koriste i derivacije funkcije $f$

\begin{align*}
I(f) = \int^b_a f(x) dx.
\end{align*}

\par
Opća integracijska formula ima oblik

\begin{align*}
I(f) = \I_m(f)+\E_m(f)\\,
\end{align*}

\par 
pri čemu je $m$+1 broj korištenih točaka, $I_m$($f$) pripadna aproksimacija integrala, a $E_m$($f$) pritom napravljena greška. Ovakve formule za približnu integraciju funkcija jedne varijable (tj. na jednodimenzionalnoj domeni) često se zovu i kvadraturne formule, zbog interpretacije integrala kao površine ispod krivulje.

\par 
Ako koristimo samo funkcijske vrijednosti za aproksimaciju integrala, onda aproksimacija $I_m$($f$) ima oblik

\begin{align*}
I_m(f) = \sum_{k=0}^m w^{(m)}_k f(x^{(m)}_{k}),
\end{align*}

\par
pri čemu je $m$ neki unaprijed zadani prirodni broj. Koeficijenti $x^{(m)}_{k}$ zovu se čvorovi integracije, a $w^{(m)}_k$ težinski koeficijenti.
\par
U općem slučaju, za fiksni $m$, moramo nekako odrediti $2m+2$ nepoznatih koeficijenata. Uobičajen način njihovog određivanja je zahtjev da su integracijske formule egzaktne na vektorskom prostoru polinoma što višeg stupnja.

\newpage

\section{Newton-Cotesove formule zatvorenog tipa}
Newton-Cotesove formule zatvorenog tipa imaju ekvidistantne čvorove, s tim da je prvi čvor u točki $x_0:=a$, a posljednji u $x_m:=b$. Preciznije, za zatvorenu Newton-Cotesovu formulu s $(m+1)$-nom točkom čvorovi su

\begin{align*}
x^{(m)}_{k} = x_0+kh_m, k=0,...,m, h_m = \frac{b-a}{m}\\.
\end{align*}
Osnovni oblik Newton-Cotesovih formula je:
\begin{align*}
\int^b_a f(x) dx \approx I_m (f) = \sum_{k=0}^m w^{(m)}{k} f(x_0 + kh_m).
\end{align*}

\newpage

\section{Trapezna formula}
Za izvod trapezne formule moramo izvest zatvorenu Newton-Cotesovu formulu za $m=1$, aproksimacija integrala ima oblik
\begin{align*}
I_1 (f) = w^{(1)}_{0} f(x_0) + w^{(1)}_{1} f(x_0+h_1),
\end{align*}
pri čemu je
\begin{align*}
h := h_1 = \frac{b-a}{1} = b-a,
\end{align*}
pa je $x_0=a$ i $x_1=b$. Za lakše pisanje, s obzirom da znamo da je $m=1$, izostavljamo gornje indekse u $w^{(1)}_{k}$, pišemo $w_k:=w^{(1)}_{k}$. Moramo pronaći težine $w_0$ i $w_1$, tako da integracijska formula egzaktno integrira polinome što višeg stupnja na intervalu $[a,b]$, tj. da za polinome $f$ što višeg stupnja bude
\begin{align*}
\int^b_a f(x) dx = I_1(f) = w_0 f(a) + w_1 f(b).
\end{align*}
Nakon toga redom stavljamo uvjete na bazu vektorskog prostora polinoma. Ako je $f$ neki od polinoma baze vektorskog prostora, morate ćemo izračunati njegov integral. Zbog toga je preporučljivo odmah izračunati integrale oblika
\begin{align*}
\int^b_a x^k dx, k \ge 0,
\end{align*}
a zatim rezultat koristiti za razne $k$. Vrijedi
\begin{align*}
\int^b_a x^k dx = \frac{x^{k+1}}{k+1} \arrowvert^b_a = \frac{b^{k+1} - a^{k+1}}{k+1}.
\end{align*}
Za $f(x) = 1= x^0$ dobivamo
\begin{align*}
b-a = \int^b_a x^0 dx = w_0 \cdot 1 + w_1 \cdot 1.
\end{align*}
Odmah je očito da iz jedne jednadžbe ne možemo odrediti dva nepoznata parametra, pa moramo zahtjevati da integracijska formula bude egzaktna i na polinomima stupnja 1. Za $f(x) = x$ dobivamo
\begin{align*}
\frac{b^2 - a^2}{2} = \int^b_a x dx = w_0 \cdot a + w_1 \cdot b.
\end{align*}
Sada imamo dvije jednadžbe s dvije nepoznanice
\begin{align*}
w_0 + w_1 = b-a
aw_0 + bw_1 = \frac{b^2 - a^2}{2}.
\end{align*}
Pomnožimo li prvu jednadžbu s $(-a)$ i zbrojimo s drugom, dobivamo
\begin{align*}
(b-a)w_1 = \frac{b^2 - a^2}{2} - a(b-a) = \frac{b^2 -2ab+a^2}{2} = \frac{(b-a)^2}{2}.
\end{align*}
Budući da je $a \neq b$, dijeljenjem s $b-a$, dobivamo
\begin{align*}
w_1=\frac{1}{2}(b-a) = \frac{h}{2}.
\end{align*}
Drugu težinu $w_0$ lako izračunamo iz prve jednadžbe linearnog sustava
\begin{align*}
w_0=b-a-w_1=\frac{1}{2}(b-a)=\frac{h}{2},
\end{align*}
pa je $w_0=w_1$.
Vidimo da je integracijska formula $I_1(f)$ dobivena iz egzaktnosti na svim polinomima stupnja manjeg ili jednakog 1, i glasi
\begin{align*}
\int^b_a f(x) dx \approx \frac{h}{2} (f(a)+f(b)).
\end{align*}
Ta izvedena formula koju smo dobili zove se trapezna formula. Sredimo li tu formulu dobivamo:
\begin{align*}
\int^b_a f(x) dx \approx \frac{f(a) + f(b)}{2}(b-a),
\end{align*}
Sama geometrijska interpretacija te formule na sljedećem grafu nam prikazuje da je $\frac{f(a)+f(b)}{2}$ srednjica, a $b-a$ visina trapeza

\end{document}
```

Comment: Welcome to TeX.SX! You cannot simply change the extension of the `.tex` file to `.pdf`: that's not how TeX works. Instead, you run a *compiler* on an input `.tex` file, which produces the output `.pdf` as a separate file.

Comment: Welcome to TeX SE! Could you clarify your question? I'm afraid I'm not sure exactly what you mean. Is it the `.tex` file which you cannot open? Or is it the `.pdf`? Did you really save your source code as a `.pdf` by mistake?

Comment: hey, ty for ur respond

Comment: i can open my .tex file but i dont know exactly convert it to .pdf

Comment: i have miktex 2.9 and ive tryed pdftex and 2 or 3 other options but that pdf file i create from .tex file always showing error

Comment: What is the error?

Comment: You haven't defined \I, \E or it should have been just an "I" or "E". Please check!

Comment: @AmbikaVanchinathan im a big newbie pls explain, i didnt choose to use program like this its only my college wannabe proffersor's idea... 
Error is: Adobe reader cant open file becase that sort of file is not supported or may be corrupted

Comment: There is an error in the .tex file. So it cannot create a .pdf file. You need to correct the error first to get the pdf.

Comment: @AmbikaVanchinathan tyvm! pls tell me there is some sort of reader that tells u atleast a line of error :(

Comment: MiKTeX would have prompted the errors as "Undefined control sequence ..." while compiling the file.

Comment: Your editor can usually show you the exact error message. If not, you can look in the `.log` file yourself. There will usually be a line number. It may or may not be the number of the line where the error is to be found but it is a good place to start. There will certainly be an error message. It may or may not mean much to you but it may well help people here to help you. Please do not write in txt spk. It is much harder to read and is especially difficult for non-native speakers.

Comment: @AmbikaVanchinathan i have 200MB MiKTeX version should i download the 1.7GB full one?

Comment: You will still need to fix errors in your code. Unless the error involves a package not being found, downloading more software will not solve it.

Comment: I underestand i will need to fix the errors, where can i find .log file?

Comment: In the directory where you have the `.tex` file usually.

Comment: In the directory where your .tex file is

Comment: i have saved it on my desktop and ther isnt a one :(

Comment: omg ive realized now what a big green play button does XD thank you all for clarifying things for me, sorry for this kind of post

Answer (score 5, accepted):

[image: screenshot after compilation]

It seems you are preparing a piece on numerical methods. The problem causing all the trouble seems to be in line 60 to line 62:

```
\begin{align*}
I(f) = \I_m(f)+\E_m(f)\\,
\end{align*}
```

the "\" operator is the beginning of perhaps all TeX commands (as far as I know), and adding it here might have been troublesome. Changing it to the form below seemed to have worked. The image included is a screenshot after compilation.

```
\begin{align*}
I(f) = I_m(f)+E_m(f)\\,
\end{align*}
```

Comment: thank you man for looking and solving a problem for me :*